# VSCode Snippet Insertion Variable Color

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've tried many VSCode color themes, and all have the same problem for me. I cannot read the area of the snippet variable I'm typing in because the text and background almost match. I've tried adjusting properties in the theme and none seem to work. Wondering which item I need to change in the theme to edit the background color of variables being entered for snippets if it exists.

Properties I've tried:

```
{
  "editor.findMatchBackground": "#b7c5d380",

  "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#b7c5d330",

  "editor.findRangeHighlightBackground": "#243E51",

  "editor.hoverHighlightBackground": "#333F4A",

  "editor.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#1D252C",

  "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#28313a",
  "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#28313a",
  "editor.rangeHighlightBackground": "#28313a",

  "editor.selectionBackground": "#28323a",

  "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#28313a",

  "editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground": "#41505e",

  "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#FFFFFF0D"
}
```

[image: sco]

Comment: Note: after asking this question I found this guide. Had I seen this I would have been able to find the snippets section. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.snippetTabstopHighlightBackground": "#ff0000",
}
```

or other `snippet` colors that can be changed:

```
"editor.snippetFinalTabstopHighlightBackground": "#ff0000",
"editor.snippetFinalTabstopHighlightBorder": "#ff0000",
"editor.snippetTabstopHighlightBorder": "#ff0000",
```

I just typed `snippet` into the `colorCustomizations` options and Intellisense found those.

Comment: Adding `"editor.snippetTabstopHighlightBackground": "#color",` did the trick!